# Run task weekly and only 4 times on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scheduler

I want to run a rake task 4 times on Sunday only.

I was thinking of doing the following:

1. check if its Sunday => Time.now.wday = 0
2. Check if the time is less than 4 am => Time.now < 4:00:00

I would run the task every hour.

Syntax:

```
if Time.now.wday == 0 && Time.now < 4:00:00
              rake "some_rake_task"
         end
```

Would the above work?

Comment: How do you schedule your jobs on Heroku? Are you using the Heroku Scheduler Addon, or an additional dyno running a clockwork instance, or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the following

```
task :get_resource_scores => :environment do 
   #If this is in production mode or staging mode then only get the scores 4 times on Sunday between midnight and 4 am
   if  Time.now.wday == 7 && Time.now.hour < 5
     get_resource_scores
   end
end
```